# Why two N-channel MOSET instead of one P-channel?

Tags: mosfet, pmos

Today I saw the schematic of a lenovo G480-la-7981p ([download](http://www.repairalaptop.com/ibm-lenovo-g480-la-7981p-free-laptop-schematic/) or [download](http://www.repairalaptop.com/download/IBM%20Lenovo%20G480%20LA-7981p%20Free%20Laptop%20Schematic.pdf)). On page 23 you can see this part:

[image: image1]

I mean this part/configuration:

[image: image2]

They've used two N-channel MOSETs instead of one P-channel. why?

Edit: Page of [DMN66D0LDW](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/DMN66D0LDW-7/DMN66D0LDWDICT-ND/1774238)

Comment: Usually one of two reasons: RDSon or it was already on the BOM.

Comment: Because when you replace this with one PMOS, the load **must** use 3.3 V as supply voltage otherwise the PMOS cannot be switched **OFF**. This design makes it an "open drain" output which can switch a load to any supply as long as Vds_max of the right transistor is not exceeded.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks, would you provide your answer with explanation and calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two N-FETs permit the signal to pass through in a net non-inverted state. It also maintains the ability for the THERM_TRIP signal to be open drain to GND to activate - meaning that it can be easily wire-ORed if you have more than one source of over temperature detection.

A P-FET does not do these things in this same way.

Answer (score 3):

if OVERT# == LO then output transistor is conducting

if OVERT# == HI then output transistor is not conducting

N-CH MOSFET has lower Rdson compared to its complementary P-CH part, also the actual is switching GND, the P-CH would have to switch Vcc.